# Connecting to WebAPI from different clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've come across a number of posts describing the Web API pipeline.  In particular, I saw how you are able to inject some code into the MessageHandlers by inheriting from DelegateHandlers.  The exciting part of this feature is you can wrap your Authentication plumbing in the handler.

Here is an example:

http://sixgun.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/asp-net-web-api-basic-authentication/

In most of the examples, I have only seen C# clients using the HttpClient class to call into WEB Api.

How would other clients connect to my Web Api service if I implement a custom handler to manage my Authentication?

In others words, how would an Android, iOS, or AJAX application connect to my service?  Do each of these clients have to implement 'their' version of HttpClient so they can perform an SendAsync?

Thanks.

Steve

Comment: The WebApi server is just http.  Each of those clients have libraries to send http requests ...

Comment: And in your example with basic authentication, basic auth is just an http header with user name & password base64 encoded.